# Find the percentage of Non-Null rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Oh SQL, why do you frustrate me...

Good afternoon everyone, I'm stuck....again....

I have a DB that holds the information for a form (duh), this form can be "Saved" so that the user can come back and work on it later. What I need, is to find the percentage of fields that are NOT NULL. For instance;

```
COL_A |COL_B |COL_C |ETC.. z  %  
-------------------------- z------
  X   |   X  | NULL |      z  66 
  X   |   X  |   X  |      z  100
 NULL | NULL |   X  |      z  33
 NULL | NULL | NULL |      z  0
```

The icing on the cake? There are 47 columns that need to be checked for each row. I may be going about this the wrong way. Any help/tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You may want to try `unpivot` to turn those 47 columns into rows.

Comment: Is the number of columns likely to change often?

Comment: No, number of columns will always be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` combined with `VALUES`:

```
SELECT t.*, FLOOR(100 * (1.0 * sub.col)/sub.counter) AS [percentage]
FROM #tab t
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT COUNT(c), COUNT(*) 
   FROM (VALUES(t.col1), (t.col2), (t.col3), (t.col4), (t.col5),
               (t.col6), (t.col7), (t.col8), (t.col9), (t.col10)) AS s(c)
 ) AS sub(col, counter)
```

You need to add cols up to 47 in `VALUES` clause.

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/415133)**</kbd>

**EDIT:**

The solution above works when columns have similiar datatype or there exists implicit conversion. If there are datatypes where there is no implicit conversion it will fail (like `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` and `DATETIME`. One quick workaround is to wrap every column with `CAST(t.colx AS NVARCHAR(100))`:

```
SELECT t.*, FLOOR(100 * (1.0 * sub.col)/sub.counter) AS [percentage]
FROM #tab t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(c), COUNT(*) 
             FROM (VALUES 
             (CAST(t.col1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))), 
             (CAST(t.col2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))), 
             (CAST(t.col3 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))), 
             (CAST(t.col4 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))), 
             (CAST(t.col5 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))), 
             (CAST(t.col6 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))), 
             (CAST(t.col7 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))), 
             (CAST(t.col8 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))), 
             (CAST(t.col9 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))), 
             (CAST(t.col10 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))
             ) AS s(c)) AS sub(col, counter)
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/415155)**</kbd>

Alternatively `IIF/CASE` can be used (no more concerns about datatypes):

```
SELECT t.*, FLOOR(100 * (1.0 * sub.col)/sub.counter) AS [percentage]
FROM #tab t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(c), COUNT(*) 
             FROM (VALUES 
             (IIF(t.col1 IS NULL, NULL, 1)), 
             (IIF(t.col2 IS NULL, NULL, 1)),
             (IIF(t.col3 IS NULL, NULL, 1)), 
             (IIF(t.col4 IS NULL, NULL, 1)),
             (IIF(t.col5 IS NULL, NULL, 1)), 
             (IIF(t.col6 IS NULL, NULL, 1)),
             (IIF(t.col7 IS NULL, NULL, 1)), 
             (IIF(t.col8 IS NULL, NULL, 1)),
             (IIF(t.col9 IS NULL, NULL, 1)), 
             (IIF(t.col10 IS NULL, NULL, 1))
             ) AS s(c)) AS sub(col, counter);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo3`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/415162)**</kbd>

Comment: @lad2025..will this work with all `null` values in a row? and without an `id` column?

Comment: @vkp Yes, it will work with all  NULLs, I add id as PK column, OP can remove it **[demo without ID](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/415132)**

Comment: excellent..perfect solution as always :) i checked it just now.

Comment: @lad2025 Getting an Operand type clash: Uniqueidentifier is incompatible with datetime. I believe the clash is coming from the variable c because it's listed as a uniqueidentifier?

Comment: @Kramb Well this is problem when you have various datatypes and there is no implicit conversion. One quick workaround is to `CAST(t.col1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))` each column. I will think about cleaner solution

Comment: That did it for me. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could have the application that collects the data count the unfinished rows and save it with the record.  You could also create a calculated field to store the saved percentage value automatically when the record is saved.

Example with 3 columns:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [COL_A] [varchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [COL_B] [nchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [COL_C] [nchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [PctSaved]  AS 
            ((case when [COL_A] IS NULL then (1) else (0) end
            +case when [COL_B] IS NULL then (1) else (0) end)
            +case when [COL_C] IS NULL then (1) else (0) end/(3.0)
            ) PERSISTED
) ON [PRIMARY]
```